Who's who in the Oranienburg scenes in "The Zone of Interest"?
Towards the end of Jonathan Glazer's film The Zone of Interest (2023), there are a few scenes that take place in a building (or buildings) among senior officials managing the KL system. I'm curious exactly who these individuals are and where the meetings are taking place, specifically:

In what building do the larger meeting and the meeting with Höss's superior take place? (I assume this is IKL?)

Who are the senior individuals depicted (e.g., the superior that Höss meets with in his office, the higher-ranking individuals in the large meeting)? For example, do we see Eicke?


Any insights are appreciated.
